# Match word only in codemirror simplemode

Tags: javascript, regex, codemirror, lexer, codemirror-modes

I am trying to write a very generic editor, and wanted to highlight any known keywords, no context awareness required.

I created the following regex

```js
    var commonAttributes = ["var", "val", "let", "if", "else", "export", "import", "return", "static", "fun", "function", "func", "class", "open", "new", "as", "where", "select", "delete", "add", "limit", "update", "insert"]
    let standalonePrefix = "(?<=[\\s]|^|[\\(,:])"
    let standaloneSuffix = "(?=[\\s\\?\\!,:\\)\\();]|$)"
```

and the following state.

```js
    {
          regex: new RegExp(standalonePrefix+"("+commonAttributes.join("|")+")"+standaloneSuffix, "i"),
          token: "keyword"
    },
```

I understand that to match at line beginning , I would have to use sol: true, as ^ has no meaning in our context. But this causes problems for me.
without sol: true, writing

> **let** leaf**let** **let**

will highlight all lets.
with sol: true,
only first let will match

> **let** leaflet let

My desired outcome is that i get,

> **let** leaflet **let**

How can I do so?

Comment: Don't word boundaries work for you? `new RegExp("\\b("+commonAttributes.join("|")+")\\b", "i")`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thats the exact problem, ^ \b wont work because when code mirror matches the token it would separate leaflet as leaf and let. so the word boundary would check out. So i will still get what I am getting right now. **let** leaf**let** **let** ,

Answer (score 0):

Since I couldnt find anything to work around this, I ended up using a workaround.

I removed ^ from my prefixes, and created another state with ^ and sol: true.

```js
let standalonePrefix = "(?<=[\\s]|[\\(,:])"
```

```js
{
        regex: new RegExp(standalonePrefix+"("+commonAttributes.join("|")+")"+standaloneSuffix, "i"),
        token: "keyword"
},
{
        regex: new RegExp("(?:^)("+commonAttributes.join("|")+")"+standaloneSuffix, "i"),
        sol: true,
        token: "keyword"
},
```